# Introducing characters in a screenplay

Tags: characters, screenwriting

In one of my scenes, I introduce "GUEST" at a party. Later, each guest is introduced by name. So if I capitalized GUESTS, do I have to capitalize their name later?

Comment: Names are capitalized. It's unclear if you are going for an artistic effect.

Comment: So do I need to capitalize the GUESTS seen at a party too? I don't want it to confuse the reader, first we have GUESTS, then we have the same people but we discover their name PETER, MARY, JOHN, and CARRIE, for instance. Sorry this is my first try at a screenplay!

Comment: Screenplays are not for "readers". Screenplays are for actors (and directors) so they communicate things that are intended for *production*, not *narrative mystery*. If you introduce a character who later has a name, use the character name from the start and always call them by their name. If you need a guest that has no name they can be GUEST 1, GUEST 2 – but keep it consistent.

Comment: Look on your bookshelf. How do other scripts do it?

Comment: @wetcircuit Can I suggest making your comment an actual answer? It seems it was what the question required after all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screenplay dialogue tags for unintroduced characters](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/50806/screenplay-dialogue-tags-for-unintroduced-characters)

Comment: (Your question was asked first, but the question I linked to ended up getting a better answer. So I think marking this question as the "duplicate" will be more helpful to future readers.)

Answer (score 1):

Wetcircuit is right.  Use the person's name.  Even if it's never stated out loud in the entire screenplay.  Because the role still needs to be cast.